# HTML/CSS nested left border: reiterative visual effect

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nested-lists

I'm after this nested `border-left` effect on HTML lists.  Notice how with each nested level of the list, the left border encroaches one step:

[image]

Strictly more like this without much of a gap between the listed term and bullet:

[image]

Here is a minimal example to play with:

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
  <li>RPG
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li>DA</li>
      <li>Bioshock</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>MOBA
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li>DOTA</li>
      <li>LoL</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can you please suggest how to implement the nested left margin effect in HTML/CSS?  **Edit: this has to work for an infinite, open-ended number of nesting levels.**

Comment: what've you tried so far? this is not a service code site

Comment: @dippas: the only solution I've tried is similar to thebrownkid's answer below, but it doesn't work for an unspecified number of nesting levels.  The genius of the correct solution would be able to step up the left border reiteratively without PHP/JS, but only with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use the `border-left` style to achieve what you want.**

**EDIT -** *To answer OP's question in comments*

> 1) **To get infinity nested lists with borders**

Add the above-mentioned style to `ul` which will target parent and all child ul's respectively to give a border-left.

```
ul {
    border-left: 20px solid #000;
}
```

As adding border-left to the parent element increases the border for the child element as well. This should be fine *if you don't have varying borders.*

> 2) **To get custom borders for lists -**

Basically, I removed all the padding for the lists i.e. `ul` and then added `20px` `border-left` to the `parent list` and another `20px` `border-left` to the `child list`.

For a `grand-child` `ul` procedure is the same, if you give that `ul` the classname -> `grand-child`, the css would look like -

```
ul.grandchild li {
    border-left: 30px solid #000;
}
```

**Working snippet with `parent` and `child` `ul` is as follows -**

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}


/*
for different border sizes

ul.parent li {
  border-left: 20px solid #000; 
}

ul.child li {
  border-left: 20px solid #000;
}
*/

/* for all ul's with same radius, don't need any specific class */
ul {
  border-left: 20px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li>RPG
    <ul class="child">
      <li>DA</li>
      <li>Bioshock</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>DA</li>
          <li>Bioshock</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>MOBA
    <ul class="child">
      <li>DOTA</li>
      <li>LoL</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

*P.S. Adding border-left to the parent element increases the border for the child element which you must have understood anyway.*

Comment: Is there a way to do this for an infinite number of nesting levels without me having to give each nesting level an explicit class?

Comment: I've updated my post to meet your condition @ptrcao. I hope it helps!

Comment: @ptrcao Dont forget to accept the answer. Happy coding!